# SQLite error, missing database...I cannot understand the error

Tags: android, sqlite

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong? I am trying to add an event to database and the print it when I click a menu item. 
I have a SQLite Helper with the following method:

```
public void addEvent(Event ev){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, ev.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.START_DATE, ev.getStartTime());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.END_DATE, ev.getEndTime());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.IMAGE_URL, ev.getImageURL());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.URL, ev.getUrl());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.SUBTITLE, ev.getSubtitle());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION, ev.getDescription());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}
```

And here is where I create the event, add it to the database and print it:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getTitle().equals("Sort by name")){
        EventsListFragment.sort(-1);
    }else if (item.getTitle().equals("Sort by date")) {
        EventsListFragment.sort(1);
    }else if (item.getTitle().equals("Stored events")){
        Event event = new Event("AURORA", "Mon 23.25.2016 at 15:30:00", "Mon 23.25.2016 at 16:30:00", "g", "g", "g", "g");
        eventsDB.addEvent(event);
        printDatabase();
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then I get this error which I cannot understand.

```
05-24 23:02:01.068 2453-2453/com.example.aurora.eventsapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "date": syntax error
05-24 23:02:01.068 2453-2453/com.example.aurora.eventsapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Subtitle=g Image=g Description=g Title=AURORA End date=End: Mon 23.25.2016 at 16:30:00 URL=g Start date=Start: Mon 23.25.2016 at 15:30:00
                                                                            android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "date": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO stored_events_table(Subtitle,Image,Description,Title,End date,URL,Start date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                                                                            #################################################################
                                                                            Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
                                                                            Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
```

===================UPDATE===========================

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "storedevents.db";
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "stored_events_table";

 public static final String ID = "_id";
 public static final String TITLE = "Title";
 public static final String START_DATE = "StartDate";
 public static final String END_DATE = "EndDate";
 public static final String IMAGE_URL = "Image";
  public static final String URL = "URL";
 public static final String SUBTITLE = "Subtitle";
 public static final String DESCRIPTION = "Description";

public static final String[] ALL_COLUMNS = new String[] {ID, TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, IMAGE_URL, URL, SUBTITLE, DESCRIPTION};
public static final String[] LIST_COLUMNS = new String[] {TITLE, START_DATE, END_DATE, IMAGE_URL, URL, SUBTITLE, DESCRIPTION};

public static String[] stringArray(long id) {
    return new String[] {Long.toString(id)};
}

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
        ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT " +
        TITLE + " text not null " +
        START_DATE + " text not null " +
        END_DATE + " text not null " +
        IMAGE_URL + " text " +
        URL + " text " +
        SUBTITLE + " text " +
        DESCRIPTION + " text);";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add new row to the database
public void addEvent(Event ev){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, ev.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.START_DATE, ev.getStartTime());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.END_DATE, ev.getEndTime());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.IMAGE_URL, ev.getImageURL());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.URL, ev.getUrl());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.SUBTITLE, ev.getSubtitle());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.DESCRIPTION, ev.getDescription());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}

//Delete event from database
public void deleteEvent(String eventTitle){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + "WHERE " + TITLE + "=\"" + eventTitle + "\";" );
}

//Print the database as string
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString="";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE 1";

    //points to a location in results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title")) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Title"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

}

Comment: your columns are named `End date` and `Start date`. that could be a problem.

Comment: have you edited table schema ? if yes so you have to increase  DB_VERSION ? and your columns name i think you put space in " end date" ? columns can't have space in their name

Comment: I changed to EndDate and StartDate and now it says " table stored_events_table has no column named EndDate" but I don't understand why because I have it there in the code

Comment: Please show us your `DatabaseHelper` class - specifically where you declare the column names. I also suspect these names (containing spaces) may be the cause of the error.

Comment: I have also changed the version and still same error

Comment: If you changed column names - then you need to update the actual database table.

Comment: You also need to add commas between one field and the next one

Comment: How and where should I write this update?

Comment: Problem solved after adding commas and uninstalling and running the app again. Now it runs but when I click the item in the menu it just doesn't respond anymore, it freezes. >:(

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you have an SQL error in the statement

```
INSERT INTO stored_events_table(Subtitle,Image,Description,Title,End date,URL,Start date)
       VALUES ...
```

Column name can't contain space symbol - please check you code\constants where you define\construct the SQL statemnent.